# If map can be defined using Foldable, why is Functor not mentioned in definition of Foldable

Tags: haskell, functor, foldable

I read that, `map` can be defined using `foldr`, i.e. it is a primitive recursive function. At least for lists.

Now my question: Why is Functor not a sub type class of Foldable? And if `fmap` can only be defined in terms of `foldr` for lists, what makes them special?

Looking at a definition of `map` with foldr:

```
myMap f xs = foldr step [] xs
    where step x ys = f x : ys
```

I could use Monoids to get to:

```
myMap f xs = foldr step mempty xs
    where step x ys = f x : ys
```

But sadly I'm not much enough of a Haskell magician to get away with `cons`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's simply a silly idea. On another note, Functor and Foldable are not types, nor are there subtypes in Haskell.

Comment: `IO` is a functor. Let’s say there’s an `x = readLn :: IO Int`. `foldr (+) 0 x` must be an `Int`. What is it?

Comment: @Ingo Then how do you call the relation between `Applicative` and `Functor`. Just "every `Applicative` must be an instance of `Functor`"

Comment: It's type classes, not types, and hence super/sub-classes.

Comment: `Foldable` is too list-centric, it basically allows one to efficiently run `foldr f x . toList`. It will not distinguish between trees having the same in-order visit. Instead, `fmap f` will preserve all the tree structure.

Answer (score 9):

> But sadly I'm not much enough of a Haskell magician to get away with cons.

You've found the fundamental problem that disallows making every Foldable a Functor; `foldr` discards the *structure* that is folded, keeping only (what amounts to) a list of its elements. You can't "get away with cons" because you *can't know* what the structure of the data is given only a `Foldable` instance.

Given this (typical) definition of a tree:

```
data Tree a = Bin a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Tip

instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Bin a l r) = Bin (f a) (fmap f l) (fmap f r)
  fmap _ Tip = Tip

instance Foldable Tree where
  foldMap f (Bin a l r) = foldMap f l <> f a <> foldMap f r
  foldMap _ Tip = mempty
```

Compare these two trees:

```
let x = Bin 'b' (Bin 'a' Tip Tip) Tip
let y = Bin 'a' Tip (Bin 'b' Tip Tip)
```

Both trees have a `toList` of "ab", but are clearly different. This means that the act of folding the tree loses some information (namely, the boundary between the left subtree, right subtree, and the element) which you can not recover. Since you can't distinguish between x and y using the results from the `Foldable` instance, you can't possibly write `fmap` such that `fmap id == id` using only those methods. We had to resort to pattern matching and using constructors to write out `Functor` instance.